# Why are React URLs conflicting with Django Rest

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

Ive used this syntax multiple times before but now this is giving me issues. The Django urls that exlplicity define the template `index.html` are intended to recieve the initial reqeust for the site (`path('')...`)and return a the React app, and then any page React requests will be handled by React (`re_path(...)`). Anyway, the issue is that if I remove the "re_path grab all" url. The home page loads but any other page will not. Now this isnt too much of a concern considering in the past, I just added the regex, and it works ie . `re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$`. Now though, if this code is added, the homepage not only will NOT load, but the axios call, `retrievePicks` doesnt even hit the Django backend and instead returns `index.html` as raw (mostly unreadable) text. But I can now go to any OTHER page and it works ok. I have tried multiple things like using fetch instead of axios, using post/detailed actions (moot point since it doesnt even make it to django server), adding in Switch component, trying to redirect to another url. I cant figure out why all other axios calls work fine and this is the only one that doesnt.

My `package.json` has the proxy set to `http://localhost:8000` btw.

Im on a linux server, using Gunicorn/Nginx, and React was built with `create-react-app`

**Raw text revieved by axios**

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/lib[...]
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />

      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Route exact path="/team/:name" component={TeamDetailScreen} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**pickActions**

```
export const retrievePicks = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type:"PICKS_REQUEST"})
    try{
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/games/picks/football?week=1', config)
        dispatch({type:"PICKS_SUCCESS", payload:data})
    }catch(err){
        console.log('picks retrieval error', err.response)}

}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/games/', include('picksix.urls')),
    path('api/users/', include('user.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"))


]
```

Comment: regular expression note: `^(?:.*)/?$` is identical to `^.*/?$`, and calling `(?:...)` weird is itself weird: if you understand RE, you know what it does and therefore why it works as a Django `re_path` pattern. If you _don't_ know what it does, why are you using it? Because if your response to that is "because it works", the counter response to that is "how would you even know? All you know is that it hasn't broken _yet_, you have no idea whether it _actually_ works" =)

Comment: Remember that comments are for comments, not for answers, and remember to read the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Someone calling you out on calling perfectly normal programming constructions "weird" is on you, not on them, and if your post explains that you're using something even though you imply you don't understand why it works, they should absolutely ask you why you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to implement a solution, although I would not call it a complete "fix".
I have heard about conflicting urls when using BrowserRouter from `react-router-dom`. So i bit the bullet and used HashRouter. For obvious reasons I prefer BrowerRouter, but switching to HashRouter allows the application to work as designed. Even with the regex path `re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$` it still worked but then caused React to further 'mangle' the urls when redirecting (and simply directing), so I was able to completely remove this and the application not only works fine, but URLs are not mangled. I also had to ensure the api call to have the "/", preceeding the url (I know this is already best practice, but prior code still didnt work with or without it). The only reason I wouldnt deem it a complete fix is that I would still like to not have hashes in the url.

What i did find interesting, like I mentioned, was that all the urls and axios calls worked (get/post, query or 'static') worked except for the "/home" React route and the `retrievePicks` API call. Its as if Django was parsing the host from the incoming request object, send it to the correct view and loading react, and allowing the rest of the requested URL to go through React. But when initiaiting the axios call, it repeats that cycle in comparsion to any other page, the application is able to keep React urls (along w/ axios calls) and Django URLs separate. Oddly enough when checking the logs of the server, nothing showed out of the ordinary. I might be looking the wrong spot but this is what I found...

**Failing log of _request.META**

```py
{'wsgi.errors': <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWrapper object at 0x7fd92c612580>, 'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.multithread': False,
'wsgi.multiprocess': True, 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper'>, 'wsgi.input_terminated': True, 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/20.1.0', 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7fd92c612700>, 'gunicorn.socket': <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=/tmp/picksixcity.com.socket>, 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'RAW_URI': '/home', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close', 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9', 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://picksixcity.com/team/DAL', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'PATH_INFO': '/home', 'SCRIPT_NAME': ''}
/home # this route fails
```

**Working log of _request.META**

```py
{'wsgi.errors': <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWrapper object at 0x7fd92cd21fa0>, 'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.multithread': False, 'wsgi.multiprocess': True, 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper'>, 'wsgi.input_terminated': True, 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/20.1.0', 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7fd92ccb3970>, 'gunicorn.socket': <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=/tmp/picksixcity.com.socket>, 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'RAW_URI': '/team/DAL', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'HTTP_HOST':
'localhost', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close', 'HTTP_PRAGMA': 'no-cache', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'no-cache', 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'PATH_INFO': '/team/DAL', 'SCRIPT_NAME': ''}
/team/DAL # this is the route
```

I agree that copy/pasting code one doesnt understand is leaning towards the results of "when it fails" vs "if it fails", but if anyone who has experienced this or can explain why this is/was happening, I would appreciate. Im familiar with basic regex but in my short time I have not had to create too complex a pattern